# How do I edit out old include paths in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on a project that originally had all of its .cpp and .h files in the same diectory (the src folder).

As the project is growing larger though, I wanted to seperate the files into their own subdirectories. However, after doing this, VS gives the error that the files are no longer included in the project becasue I moved them to a new directory. I then right-clicked on each file and selected "include file in project". It loaded and my errors went away.

Problem is that now when I try to compile I get an error saying cannot open the source file "src/fileName.cpp" No such file or directory. But, of course that file isnt there anymore because I moved it!

I could be misunderstanding but it seems to me that VS is still holding on to the old include paths even though the files were moved and the new paths were included. Since I added these files using the right-click method I mentioned I don't know how to navigate the project properties to get rid of the old paths that were included by default.

For clarity:

Old project structure:

```
src:
 - game.cpp
 - game.h
 - logger.cpp
 - logger.h
```

new project structure:

```
src:
 - Game
    - game.h
    - game.cpp
 - Logger
    - logger.h
    - logger.cpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my issue from someone on Reddit.

I had to unload my project to get access to the project files (.vcxproj). Once here I used the search function to find and manually remove the old include and compile paths. After reloading the project the issue was resolved.